# Custom emoji on react? JDA

Tags: java, discord-jda

How can I get custom emojis from my server? Not per unicode?

```
package de.backxtar.listener;

import net.dv8tion.jda.api.events.message.guild.GuildMessageReceivedEvent;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.hooks.ListenerAdapter;

public class ReactMessageListener extends ListenerAdapter {

    public void onGuildMessageReceived(GuildMessageReceivedEvent event){

        if(event.getChannel().getId().equals("635352238256029706")) {
            event.getMessage().addReaction("U+1F44D").complete();
            event.getMessage().addReaction("U+1F44E").complete();
        }
    }
}
```

This function is working with unicode emojis.. but I want to react with my custom emojis ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/Message.html#addReaction(java.lang.String)) has an example that outlines how to use the method. You can use a custom emoji by passing `"name:id"`. To get the id of a custom emoji, send it to some discord channel with backslash infront of the emoji: `\:name:`. This will render it in the raw mention format `<:name:id>` which contains the id and name you need.